# How to remove extra quotes from each column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Removing extra quotes from each column values, following are my column values:

```
Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array("58, ""management"", ""married"", ""tertiary"", ""no"", 2143, ""yes"", ""no"", ""unknown"", 5, ""may"", 261, 1, -1, 0, ""unknown"", ""no"""), Array("4
4, ""technician"", ""single"", ""secondary"", ""no"", 29, ""yes"", ""no"", ""unknown"", 5, ""may"", 151, 1, -1, 0, ""unknown"", ""no"""), Array("33, ""entrepreneur"", ""married"", ""secondary
"", ""no"", 2, ""yes"", ""yes"", ""unknown"", 5, ""may"", 76, 1, -1, 0, ""unknown"", ""no"""))
```

**Expected output:**

```
Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(58, management, married, tertiary, no, 2143, yes, no, unknown, 5, may, 261, 1, -1, 0, unknown, no), Array(44, technician, single, secondary, no, 29, yes, no, unknown, 5, may, 151, 1, -1, 0, unknown, no), Array(33, entrepreneur, married, secondary, no, 2, yes, yes, unknown, 5, may, 76, 1, -1, 0, unknown, no))
```

Following is the code:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val data = sc.textFile("simplilearn/Project 1_dataset_bank-full.csv")
val header = data.first()

val data1 = data.filter(row=>row != header)
val finalSet = data1.map(row=>row.split(";"))
```

The above RDD is stored in `finalSet` RDD.

Comment: can you show us some lines of your dataframe by doing df.show()?

Comment: Ramesh i had not created dataframe yet still facing issue in removing the quotes from RDD, after which i will store it in a dataframe.

Comment: I tried the following but not getting any value:                                              val finalData = finalSet.foreach{row=>row.foreach{x=>x.replace("\"","")}}
finalData: Unit = ()                                                                                                where my finalSet contains the above RDD.

Comment: how did you get the finalSet can you paste the code in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove all quotes when creating the final RRD. Replace the line

```
val finalSet = data1.map(row=>row.split(";"))
```

with

```
val finalSet = data1.map(row => row.split(";").map(_.trim.replace("\"", "")))
```